# Saving a webpage without the pound sign (#) when title has it

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

When I save a complete webpage with either Chrome or IE, both Chrome and IE defaults to using the title as the filename, and if the webpage has a title which contains a pound sign (e.g. Point #1), the filename will contain the pound sign.

The problem occurs when I open the saved page in Chrome / IE, and the images don't show because the pound sign is not properly escaped in the URL, so the image files in the folder are not loaded. E.g. spaces are escaped with %20, and pound should be escaped with %23.

Is there a way (or extensions) to make Chrome/IE remove/escape all pound signs in the filename when saving webpages, without manually doing so?

Thanks.